# Does Python's logging level affect performance?

Tags: python, performance, logging

I'm working on a project where speed is crucial. Even though it's just a proof of concept at this stage (will be ported to some other language later on), I'd like to optimise the code as much as possible. I'm going to use Python's logger quite extensively so I'd like a way to disable logging without having to remove every logging method.

I know this can be done by setting the logging level, but does Python actually skip the line? Or is it being interpreted and then ignored?
If the latter is the case: are there any other methods to get the result I'm seeking?

Comment: Why not add the code that disables logging as a command line argument and then benchmark it yourself?

Comment: Good point, I’ll give that a try. Though I’d like to know more about how python handles the logs internally :)

Comment: me too :), but some data points to refer to always make the discussion richer!

Comment: Once you have some data, feel free to update the question or answer yourself, it would really be useful.

Comment: Will do later today! Meetings and stuff... ;)